# best approach of ngFor to consider every nth elements only

Tags: angular, ngfor

What is the best approach to iterate only on every n'th multiple of list using `ngFor`. Currently, I would get all `n` multiple in `.ts` file and use them in `ngFor`. Is there a better approach like generating these multiples in template, at `ngFor` or any other better means of simplification.

-- * .ts file *--

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.req_Indeces=[];
    this.incidentCount = this.incidentList.length;
    for(var i=0;(n*i)<this.incidentCount;i++){
      this.req_Indeces.push(n*i);
    
    }
    console.log(this.req_Indeces);
  }
```

-- * .html file *--

```
            <ul *ngFor="let p of req_Indeces;let i=index; first as isFirst;let x=count">
                    <li >{{incidentList[p].src}}</li> 

                    <!-- (ignore this part if don't want to go into more details) adding rest of ele between multiples -->
                    <li >{{incidentList[p].src}}</li>
                    <li >{{incidentList[(p+1)%(n*x)].src}}</li>
                    <li >{{incidentList[(p+2)%(n*x)].src}}</li>
                    .
                    <li >{{incidentList[(p+(n-1))%(n*x)].src}}</li>
                                                                                       
            </ul>
```

some more constraints:

- using `ngIf` and skipping is not an option, as it would give empty list in between the req list to display.
- for simplicity purpose consider here I considered `incidentCount`,`n` to be even.

Answer (score 1):

Building a new array (by copying the elements you want to see) is generally considered slower than just accessing them via indices, so building an array of indices you want to display should be faster. Like this:

```
indexList = [...Array(this.list.length).keys()].filter(i => i % 2 == 0);
```

Displaying it with:

```
<li *ngFor="let elm of indexList">{{list[elm]}}</li>
```

Here you also have a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rykafe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

You can package this into a directive for reusability (see stackblitz):

```
<li *myForNth="let elm of list;n: 2">{{elm}}</li>
```